# AngularJS show/hide data based on 2 different selected drop down

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I have a database table "hotels" include hotels name, address, and each type of room price. when I test to display in drop down it is working no problem.

```
<select name="hoselect" id="hoselect" ng-model="hotels$index">
<option  value="">--Don't need hotel--</option>
<option ng-repeat="Hotels in details.Hotels" value="{{Hotels.hotel_id}}"
{{Hotels.level}} / {{Hotels.name}} / {{Hotels.single}} / {{Hotels.double}} /
{{Hotels.triple}} / {{Hotels.quadruple}}</option>             
</select>
```

Right now I want have 2 different drop down, first select hotel name, then select room type and display the price in a div.

```
<select name="hoselect" id="hoselect" ng-model="hotels$index">
<option  value="">--Don't need hotel--</option>
<option ng-repeat="Hotels in details.Hotels" value="{{Hotels.hotel_id}}"
{{Hotels.level}} / {{Hotels.name}}</option>           
</select>
<select name="roomtype" id="roomtype">
<option>Single Room</option>
<option>Double Room</option>
<option>Triple Room</option>
<option>Quadruple Room</option>
</select>
<div class="order_hotel_inf">Base Cost:  <span class="hotel_cost"></div>
```

How to display the corresponding hotel cost based on select hotel name and room type?

Comment: The second `<select>` needs an `ng-model` directive and their `<option>` elements need `value` attributes. All the `<select>` elements need `ng-change` directives to invoke controller functions. For more information, see [AngularJS `<select>` directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).